# mysql group by range

Tags: mysql, database

| id | ml |
| --- | --- |
| 21 | 3.23 |
| 22 | 1.21 |
| 23 | 2.71 |
| 24 | 1.16 |
| 25 | 4.06 |
| 26 | 2.45 |

hello, I should group the data in this table according to 4 different ranges:

1. ml <3
2. 3 <= ml <4
3. 4 <= ml <5
4. ml> = 5

I'm tried:

SELECT CONCAT(ROUND(ml), '-', ROUND(ml) + 1) as `range`,  count(*) as `cont`
FROM table
group BY 1
order BY ml;

but the result is not what I want.

What's the best way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Could you post your data sample as text instead of an image?

Comment: Please right down your own code here. stack overflow is a discussion platform not a code generator.

Comment: Sorry for my bad question.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
GROUP BY CASE WHEN ml < 3 THEN 1
              WHEN ml < 4 THEN 2
              WHEN ml < 5 THEN 3
                          ELSE 4 END
```

The code assumes that `ml` cannot be NULL.